# How to see if column elements swapped in a later row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I've just been asked to help out on this, and I'm not sure I can come up with a piece of code that runs reasonably fast.

There are two columns of data: the first is the user id number of a social media user who initiates contact with someone; the second column is the user-id of the person who they initiate contact with. Further, assume that the rows are ordered by time.

I wish to see all the user-ids of people who "followed-back" their followers at a later date. This is what I have so far, and it's quite slow. How do I do this without for loops?

```
def myFun2(num):
    N = df.shape[0]
    init_follower = df['follower'][num]
    init_followee = df['followee'][num]
    for i in range(num+1,N):
        a = init_followee == df['follower'][i]
        b = init_follower == df['followee'][i]
        if a and b:
            return i

df = pd.DataFrame({'follower' : ['a', 'a', 'b'], 'followee' : ['b', 'c', 'a']})

# prints 2 because that's the row where a follows back b
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    print(myFun2(i))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Given a dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['follower', 'followee'])
df.loc[0] = [123, 111]
df.loc[1] = [123, 150]
df.loc[2] = [145, 123]
df.loc[3] = [150, 123]

df

  follower followee
0      123      111
1      123      150
2      145      123
3      150      123
```

#### "I wish to see all the user-ids of people who "followed-back" their followers..."

Use `merge` to do a "self inner join", matching your left table's `followee` to your right table's `follower`. Now, when you subset by all those rows where the left table's `follower` is the same as the right table's `followee`, you are in effect getting what you want:

```
a = df.merge(df, left_on = 'followee', right_on = 'follower')
b = a[a['follower_x'] == a['followee_y']][['follower_x', 'followee_x']].\
    reset_index().rename(columns = {'index' : 'timestamp', 'follower_x' : 'follower', 'followee_x' : 'followee'})
```

#### "...at a later date"

Assuming your rows are sorted by time, to get the followees who became followers later;

```
b['grp'] = b[['follower', 'followee']].apply(lambda x: str(np.sort(x.tolist())), axis = 1)
b['rank'] = b.groupby('grp')['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.rank(ascending = False))
b[b['rank'] == 1]['follower']
```

Output:

```
1    150
```

## EDIT:

For the dataframe you provided:

Output:

```
1    b
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wish to see all the user-ids of people who "followed-back" their
>   followers at a later date.

You can flip your dataframe and do an inner merge:

```
df_flip = pd.DataFrame(np.flip(df.values, 1), columns=df.columns)
res = df.merge(df_flip, how='inner')

print(res)

  follower followee
0        a        b
1        b        a
```

Then remove duplicates after ordering:

```
res = res[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(res.values, 1)).duplicated()]

print(res)

  follower followee
0        a        b
```